# How to populate grid view from an SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

I am trying to populate a grid view from a query I have in an SQL table through a connection string yet somehow I receive the following error.
Realistically as I am a beginner I think this is going to be an extremely simple error with the code so don't assume anything!

> "The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified"

The following is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace GridviewTOExcel
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=Richard2016DB; integrated security=SSPI");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.tblEmployee", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you got a build error

Comment: Make sure that you have a database with name `Richard2016DB` in your SQL Server and also attached it.

Comment: Yep I definitely do, and I've run the query and it also runs perfectly

Comment: can you add the stack trace also, so that it can be more clear?

Comment: Do you mind giving me a hand doing that? I am a complete novice at these things.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should send it to a DataTable first before being able to bind it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=Richard2016DB; integrated security=SSPI");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.tblEmployee", con);
    con.Open();
    DataTable table = New DataTable();
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(table);
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

You will need the following reference to use DataTable's

```
using System.Data;
```

Comment: Should the DataTable assignment line not read "DataTabe table = new DataTable();"? I tried both versions. Yours caused the da.Fill(table); line to throw an error saying table is unassigned while mine showed me the same error as before. Thanks for the help!

Comment: My apologies you're completely right.  So does or doesnt it work now in the end?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
    namespace GridviewTOExcel
    {
      public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
      {
        private SqlConnection con;
        private SqlCommand cmd;
        private string constr, query;

        private void connection()
        {
            string dbConnectiomName = "conStr"; // Set your keyname from web.config file
            constr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbConnectiomName].ToString();
            con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
        }

         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                gvBind(); // Bind Gridview on pageload
            }
        }

        // Function which bind gridview control  
        Public void gvBind(){

           connection();
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select Query"; // best practise is to use storedprocedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dap.Fill(ds);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this working? The 'public void' come through as 'type or namespace cannot be found' and 'invalid token' respectively. Not entirely sure why.